# Using gcc on multiple file objects

Tags: linux, object, gcc

In an exam I took I found myself in front of this question:

What's the result following this command?

```
gcc file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

A)Nothing, it's using the wrong syntax

B)Links the file objects but won't produce any result unless specified an output

C)An executable file a.out

I thought it was A) the wrong syntax, but I was wrong, could you guys help me figure out which is the correct answer? (I suspect the third one, but I also know that gcc won't always create an executable if ran)

p.s.
If you could give me a thorough explanation I would be very greatful

Comment: It's the third one. If not explicitly given via the `-o` option the final linked output file is `a.out`.

Comment: I see, when I use the command  " gcc -c file.c -o file.o ", file.o will ALWAYS be an executable? (Regardless of the permission of file.c, which at least will let it compile)

Comment: No. `-c` does not produce an executable. Please read gcc manual. It's all explained in the manual.

Comment: Read it, I get it now, when you use -c the source code will only go through Pre-processor, Compiler and Assembler, at this point the a.out will be produced, if we didn't include the -c option it would have continued with the linker( to transform it in an executable ), and after that the loader would have loaded it into memory, is there an option that stops at the linker part? What happens to the file if that's the case?